# Pandas: Querying a DataFrame - multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large DataFrame for which two of the columns are:

- a question code (e.g Q453)
- True or False to denote whether or not the question was answered correctly

I do not know all the possible question codes and each question has been answered multiple times. Something like:

Q666    True

Q463    True

Q056    True

Q666    False

I wish to know which question is the easiest, precisely which question has the highest ratio of attempts to correct answers.
What are the steps to achieve this using pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a sample of data from your post. Is this what you're looking for?

I made the true/false indicators lowercase strings; not sure what they are stored as in your file. If you're on python2, i believe you can change `from io import StringIO` to `from StringIO import StringIO`.

```
In [105]: import pandas as pd
     ...: from io import StringIO
     ...:
     ...: data = """Q666 True
     ...:
     ...: Q463 True
     ...:
     ...: Q056 True
     ...:
     ...: Q666 False
     ...: Q666 True
     ...:
     ...:
     ...: Q463 True
     ...:
     ...: Q056 True
     ...: Q666 False
     ...: Q463 False
     ...: Q666 False"""
     ...:

In [106]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=" ", header=None)

In [107]: df.columns = [['question', 'answer']]

In [108]: df['answer'] = df['answer'].astype("str").apply(lambda x: x.lower())

In [109]: df
Out[109]:
  question answer
0     Q666   true
1     Q463   true
2     Q056   true
3     Q666  false
4     Q666   true
5     Q463   true
6     Q056   true
7     Q666  false
8     Q463  false
9     Q666  false
```

Assign a constant value to to dataframe so we can count groupby our conditions, then move the multiindex back to where we need it.

```
In [110]: piv = (df
     ...:        .assign(val = 1)
     ...:        .groupby(["question", "answer"])
     ...:        .count()
     ...:        .unstack()['val'])
```

It's easy from here...

```
In [111]: piv['ratio'] = piv['true'] / piv.sum(axis=1)

In [112]: piv.sort_values("ratio")
Out[112]:
answer    false  true     ratio
question
Q666        3.0   2.0  0.400000
Q463        1.0   2.0  0.666667
Q056        NaN   2.0  1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I'm new to pandas so I had to learn the groupby and unstack functions but I think I understand and have been able to use your method to find the answer I was after. Cheers dude!